# Converting from a Model Type to string in python django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Following is a snapshot of one of my models in django application:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    device_type                     = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    requested_by                    = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    urgency                         = models.ForeignKey(RequestUrgency,to_field='request_urgency')
    request_must_be_satisfied_by    = models.DateField(null=True)
    reason                          = models.TextField()
    status                          = models.ForeignKey(ResuestStatus,to_field='request_status',default="PENDING")
    request_date                    = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.device_type

def __str__(self):
    return self.device_type
```

Code inside the views.py file:

```
def request_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Inside out if")
        form = RequestForm(request.POST)
        print("request form: ", form)
        print("request fields ", form.fields)
        print("errors: ",form.errors.as_data())
        if form.is_valid():
        print("errors: ",form.errors.as_data())
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

            post = form.save(commit = False)
            post.requested_by_id = request.user
            post.save()

            userdata = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
            useremail = userdata.email
            email_body_text = "Hi "+request.user.username+","+"\n"+"Your requested a repair for the following:"+"\n"\
                        +"Device Type: "+cleaned_data["device_type"]+"\n"\
                        +"Urgency: "+cleaned_data["urgency"]+"\n"\
                        +"Request must be satisfied by: "+cleaned_data["request_must_be_satisfied_by"]+"\n"\
                        +"Reason for new device: "+cleaned_data["reason"]+"\n"\
                        +"We will try to complete your request at the earliest. In case of any concerns contact the controller of operations."

            send_mail(email_subject,email_body_text,config.sender_email_id,[useremail],fail_silently=False)


        return redirect("NewRequest")

    else:
        print("Inside else")
        form = RequestForm(initial={'requested_by':request.user})
        Tp = DeviceType.objects.all()
        Tp = Tp.annotate(text=F('device_type')).values_list('text', flat=True)
        print("Tp request form: ", Tp)
        Ur = RequestUrgency.objects.all()
        Ur = Ur.annotate(text=F('request_urgency')).values_list('text', flat=True)
        form.fields["device_type"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tp, empty_label=None)
        form.fields["urgency"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ur, empty_label=None)
        return render(request, "Form_template.html", {"form": form, \
                                                  "name": "Device Request Form"})
```

Now, I have a function in my views.py that validates the data that is submitted through the django rendered form. Now, I have a situation, I want to print the data sent through the form by concatinating it with a particular string. Whenever I got to do so. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, DeviceType found
```

How should I overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to at least show the code you used.

Comment: are you asking for the code inside views.py? @DanielRoseman

Comment: do you have a __str__ method in your model??

Comment: yes @EsirKings I updated it. Then, too the situation is still the same.

Comment: Please add the code for that method here

Comment: question updated.

Comment: Do not format strings like that, use `str.format`...

Comment: Sure I will. @WillemVanOnsem. Thank you for the suf=ggestion. But, How should I overcome the issue I am currently facing?

Comment: @AishwaryShukla: this *is* the issue you are currently facing, you add strings and non-strings together. So what is a `"foo" + some_device_type` supposed to do?

Comment: I actually wanted to print a summarized view of the requested device type for the user. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you add strings and non-strings together when you construct the `email_body_text`. Python does not understand what a string together with a `device_type` is supposed to mean. This is not strange, adding a string and a number has the same problems:

```
>>> u"abc" + 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

As you see, the message is *exactly* the same, except for the fact that here we use an `int` instead of a `DeviceType`.

You better solve this by performing string formatting. This is not only more type safe (since it will call `unicode(..)` and `str(..)` behind the curtains, but is also more elegant.

But there are other problems with the view as well: for example you use `cleaned_data` instead of the `Request` object you constructed in the form, which make things easier, more elegant and readable:

```
def request_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = False)
            post.requested_by_id = request.user
            post.save()

            user = request.user
            useremail = user.email
            email_body_text = (
                u"Hi {},"
                "\nYour requested a repair for the following:"
                "\nDevice Type: {}"
                "\nUrgency: {}"
                "\nRequest must be satisfied by: {}"
                "\nReason for new device: {}"
                "\nWe will try to complete your request at the earliest."
                "In case of any concerns contact the controller of operations."
            ).format(
                user.username,
                post.device_type,
                post.urgency,
                post.request_must_be_satisfied_by,
                post.reason,
            )

            send_mail(email_subject,email_body_text,config.sender_email_id,[useremail],fail_silently=False)
            return redirect("NewRequest")
    else:
        form = RequestForm(initial={'requested_by':request.user})
        Tp = DeviceType.objects.all()
        Tp = Tp.annotate(text=F('device_type')).values_list('text', flat=True)
        print("Tp request form: ", Tp)
        Ur = RequestUrgency.objects.all()
        Ur = Ur.annotate(text=F('request_urgency')).values_list('text', flat=True)
        form.fields["device_type"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tp, empty_label=None)
        form.fields["urgency"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ur, empty_label=None)
    return render(request, "Form_template.html", {"form": form, "name": "Device Request Form"})
```

> **Note**; I advice you to migrate to Python-3.x, since Python-2.x will no longer be supported within two years: https://pythonclock.org/